# Fluctuation in resistance value

Tags: resistance, precision

I'm trying to measure the resistance of a surgical screw that seems to have a low resistance, around maybe one ohm. I use a 1908P multimeter and wires having for resistance around 0.005 ohm.

Since the screw resistance is a small value, I've tried the 4 points measurement method. I get something around 0.3 ohm, but the value changes very easily depending on the orientation of the wires (see below). It goes from 0.3 to 70 ohms.

[image: wires]

I'm wondering if it's either my circuit that is wired wrong, the screw because of its properties or if its the lack of precision of the multimeter( it a 5.5 digits) that causes that fluctuation.

Any idea of how I can improve this measurement?

Comment: On top of everything else that has been said, you simply cannot use stranded wire in prototyping sockets and expect reliable connections.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, what you show here ...

[image]

is not a 4-wire resistance measurement of the screw. it's a 4-wire measurement of the resistance of the screw plus the two wires to the screw, plus the contact resistances of the wire to screws, and wire to proto-board sockets. Of these, the contact resistances will be the most troublesome, as they vary hugely with pressure.

What you need is four discrete contact points actually on the screw, like this

[image]

This measures the resistance of the *length of screw between the voltage terminals*.

This way, the voltage drop at the current terminals doesn't contribute to the voltage measurement, and there's no current flowing at the voltage terminals.

You can interchange the current source and the voltage measurement if you like, the resistance measurement is still of the length of screw between the closest pair of terminals.

If you want to measure the whole length of the screw, be careful that the voltage leads and the current leads *do not touch each other*, as then a voltage connection could pick up some of the current lead voltage drop. Perhaps touch them on opposite sides of the screw.

Once you have four contact points on the screw, it doesn't matter if they are rusty or poor, as long as your current source can keep the current steady enough to measure the voltage.

There are limitations to how low a resistance you can measure, milliohms should be possible with this setup, as long as you have enough current available.

Unfortunately, once you are down into the millvolts of voltage drop along the screw, another error phenomenon starts to rear its ugly head, offset voltages generated at the voltage pickoff contacts. These result if the object and the probe are dissimilar metals, and vary with temperature and moisture levels. These can be mitigated to a large extent with AC excitation and measurement, or reverse the current source wires and average the two measurements, or subtract a zero current measurement.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem here is that with "wire twisted around some rough metal surface", you're simply not making a good contact.

Also, nah, the resistance of a screw of that thickness is probably so low that'll be hard to measure at all.

I don't know the properties of the alloy it's made of, but let's assume it's pure titanium.

That has an electrical specific resistivity of 420 nΩ·m.

Let me guesstimate that the cross-section of the screw's main body is something like 4 mm²; that leads to a length resistivity of

420 nΩ·m / (4 mm²) = 420·10⁻⁹ Ω·m / (4·10⁻⁶ m²) = 105 · 10⁻³ Ω/m = 105 mΩ/m

Let that screw be 4 cm long:

105 mΩ/m · 4·10⁻² m = 4.2·10⁻³ Ω = 4.2 mΩ

You can't measure that with your multimeter. That has nothing to do with the 5.5 digits (that's actually **a lot**), but with the fact that almost every single component in that multimeter has a (parasitic) resistance in the order of that.

So, whatever you're trying to achieve here: this is not the way to go about it. Let's not even mention the fact that you're not doing this under controlled temperature, and with a breadboard. The fact that you were trying to do low-resistance measurements with wire twisted around a metal surface also indicates that even if you had the equipment to do such measurements (which becomes *very* expensive very quickly, because you need a lot of *very* good connections) , you wouldn't know how to.

You might want to ask a **new** question, describing *why* you're doing this measurement, to what purpose, and how to succeed achieving  what you need to do.

Comment: I understand why you used titanium as an example of what the screw could be made of. But I don't think OP understands.

Answer (score 1):

What is the intent of your test?  Surely the resistance of the metal is irrelevant for surgical implants.  What can be more important is the galvanic resistance from corrosion of the external interface.

**The R of the screw will always be orders of magnitude lower than the contact area** of the wire or any surface contact when compared to **any insulator** which includes **any dielectric** such as bone tissue or **any   conductor** such as 24 gauge wire unless that conductor has more volume outside than inside the screw. **This would never apply to insulators such as bone.**

Any interface will still be orders of magnitude higher than the resistance of the screw between any length of threads even if it is a solid metal threaded target.  WHy? because the surface area or contact resistance is so thin that it dominates the total resistance.

Furthermore, galvanic corrosion further increases the ESR or effective series resistance and creates a chemical voltage in the result. The most compatible Noble metals used is gold for dental work but need alloys for strength are needed so  titanium   is one of the best compromises for this job.  So for dental implants the screws are fine thread alloys.

I have performed more stringent tests than yours for the purpose of achieving < 100mOhm required for UL chassis safety grounds.  We wanted to use powder-coated painted-steel chassis and I got approval from UL for my design deviation from their requirement to have a large surface area spade lug to an unpainted surface. The typ. 3 threads of engagement in steel  was sufficient to lower the resistance from an order of magnitude lower resistance in the body of the screw. The spec limit for passing 10 A fault currents thru the ground wire was 1V max.  It did not depend on needing a wide surface area spade lug , rather just 3 threads, of fine pitch  surface area, to engage the screw body to the steel chassis.

### SUMMARY

Your surface contact area resistance to and from  the screw determines the overall resistance and not the body length.

Afterthought.

**But I am curious, why is this important?**  If using this for electro-thermal surgical, electro-immuno, deoxidizing or resistive tissue burning (cauterizing) or some other reason, please explain for interest's sake.

**I agree with other answers and comments. [It must be a 4 wire Kelvin resistance method for measurement](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-8/kelvin-resistance-measurement/).**

[image]